# Cakephp email Encoding subject gives wrong characters

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I'm sending emails with cakephp and I have been testing it with the followign website:
http://spamcheck.postmarkapp.com/

I have had several problems, which one of them was the encoding of the subject.

Right now, that one is solved, following some solutions I've found in the internet. First line of the code is what i'm doing with the subject

Here's my code:

```
$newsubject='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';

$email = new Email('aws');
    $email->from(['xxxx@zzzz.zz' => 'test'])
    ->template('default','confirmation')
    ->viewVars([
        'user_email' => $emailTo,
    ])
    ->emailFormat('both')
    ->to($emailTo)
    ->subject($newsubject)
     ->replyTo('support@uphill.pt')
    ->helpers(['Html', 'Text'])
    //->attachments($attachment->path)
    ->send($message);
```

After I recieve the email, the subject shows: "=?UTF-8?B?SW5zY3Jpw6fDo28gbm8gZXZlbnRvOiBOYXRpb25hbCBDb25mZXJlbmNlIG9uIEh1bWFuIFBhcGlsbG9tYSBWaXJ1cw==?="

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I'm using Cakephp 3.3 and here's my aws email transporter config

```
'aws' => [
        'transport' => 'aws',
        'from' => 'xxxx@zzzzz.z',
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    ]
```

Here's my email:

http://pastie.org/private/hzcicqrlzx425ucanxyl5a

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why the subject is not only a string? You base64 encode your string and add UTF-8 character of course the result is what you get

Comment: @YannChabot without encoding, I get the subject correct on the email (Inscrição no evento: ...) but testing the email on that website, it says:
 1.1 SUBJ_ILLEGAL_CHARS     Subject: has too many raw illegal characters and  0.1 SUBJECT_NEEDS_ENCODING Subject is encoded but does not specify the encoding

Comment: I think what you want is utf8_encode maybe?

Comment: base64_ENCODE: This encoding is designed to make binary data survive transport through transport layers that are not 8-bit clean, such as mail bodies.

Base64-encoded data takes about 33% more space than the original data.

Comment: Used UTF_8, subject is the following: " =?UTF-8?B?InscriÃ§Ã£o no evento". EDIT: calling it this way: "utf8_encode('=?UTF-8?B?'.$subject.'?=')". If I remove the UTF part at the start, it says again SUBJECT_NEEDS_ENCODING (if I encode only the subject variable, says the same)

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version! That being said, CakePHPs `Email` class already creates encoded subjects on its own, so there is no need (it won't even work) to pass something encoded on your own. If you need further help, then you'll need to show at least the encoding configuration of your app, if set, the charset configuration of your `aws` email transport, and last but not least the source of the generated E-Mail. Maybe you somehow messed up your apps/emails encoding, or the service doesn't work properly, who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About the result :**

- You encoded the email `Subject` text with `base64`.
- So, you get the `encoded` text from your `Subject` plain text.

> You should use email `Subject` as string/plain text. Mail services doesn't `decode` your custom `encode` type automatically.

**Change your `Subject` string :**

```
$newsubject='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';
#TO
$newsubject=$subject;
```

> Search by typing `EmailTransport` or `Email` from `config/app.php` and check your email configuration is correctly configured.

Her is the details about [CakePHP 3.x Email](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html)